# temporary objects using NSFetchedResultsController as data source using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController to display data in my tableView from CoreData.

The data is downloaded from a server and stored in CoreData.

Occasionally, I would like the user to be able to search objects online and display them without adding them permanently to the local data store.

Is there a way to download the items and store them temporarily in a manner that will allow me to use an NSFetchedResultsController to display the data?  And then to allow none of the downloaded items to persist when the viewController is dismissed?

Comment: Put them in the core data store and then later delete them?

Comment: You can create a core data persistent store that only exists in memory (but you use it the same way). [Persistent store types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/persistent_store_types)